# Shutdown Ubuntu Command

Tags: linux, ubuntu, shutdown, sudo

What is the command or application that allows a user to shutdown the computer from gnome. And how does it have privileges while halt requires superuser?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It uses a DBus message.

```
dbus-send --system --print-reply --dest=org.freedesktop.Hal \
          /org/freedesktop/Hal/devices/computer \
          org.freedesktop.Hal.Device.SystemPowerManagement.Shutdown
```

Found this [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/100905/why-can-ubuntu-perform-a-shutdown-from-the-gui-even-though-it-is-prive-on-the-co).

Reboot:

```
dbus-send --system --print-reply --dest=org.freedesktop.Hal \
          /org/freedesktop/Hal/devices/computer \
          org.freedesktop.Hal.Device.SystemPowerManagement.Reboot
```

Suspend:

```
dbus-send --system --print-reply --dest=org.freedesktop.Hal \
          /org/freedesktop/Hal/devices/computer \
          org.freedesktop.Hal.Device.SystemPowerManagement.Suspend int32:1
```

Hibernate:

```
dbus-send --system --print-reply --dest=org.freedesktop.Hal \
          /org/freedesktop/Hal/devices/computer \
          org.freedesktop.Hal.Device.SystemPowerManagement.Hibernate
```

Comment: So dbus-send doesnt require root privileges?, and what is dbus?

Comment: DBus allows multiple applications to communicate together. And no, `dbus-send` does not require root to be used.

DBus is owned by root too.

Comment: Downvoted because HAL has been obsolete for about 4 years. Recent Ubuntus use either UPower or ConsoleKit for this, or possibly even Upstart directly.

Answer (score 2):

GNOME does this by sending messages over DBus to a service which already runs as root.

To shutdown or reboot using ConsoleKit:

```
gdbus call -y -d org.freedesktop.ConsoleKit \
              -o /org/freedesktop/ConsoleKit/Manager \
              -m org.freedesktop.ConsoleKit.Manager.Stop
```

```
gdbus call -y -d org.freedesktop.ConsoleKit \
              -o /org/freedesktop/ConsoleKit/Manager \
              -m org.freedesktop.ConsoleKit.Manager.Restart
```

To suspend or hibernate using UPower:

```
gdbus call -y -d org.freedesktop.UPower \
              -o /org/freedesktop/UPower \
              -m org.freedesktop.UPower.Suspend
```

```
gdbus call -y -d org.freedesktop.UPower \
              -o /org/freedesktop/UPower \
              -m org.freedesktop.UPower.Hibernate
```